# How to redirect NotFound() to my custom 404 page in ASP.NET Core 6 MVC

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-6.0

In `Program.cs` I have added this middleware:

```
app.Use(async (context, next) =>
            {
                await next();
                if (context.Response.StatusCode == 404)
                {
                    context.Request.Path = "/404";
                    await next();
                }
            });
```

And just after in my endpoints I have the 404 route setup:

```
endPoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "404",
                    pattern: "404",
                    defaults: new { controller = "Error", action = "Error404" });
```

While this works in general, I've noticed for actions where I am calling a `return NotFound()` it isn't displaying my custom 404 page. I'm presuming because the middleware isn't caught as it is set up before the endpoints.

I tried replacing my calls with a `return RedirectToRoute("404")` which works however the url the user see's is simply `/404` where I want to display my custom 404 page while retaining the url for the user (which is the default behavior of the middleware above)

How can I achieve this?

Comment: I test with a route which doesn't exsit,the route will not be changed,and the page content will be the 404 page.